# Вывод из базы в таблицы

Tags: php, mysql

Как вывести из базы Mysql в таблицу, данные только тех, кто из украины?

```html
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap-3.2.0-dist\css\bootstrap.css"> <!--css file link in bootstrap folder-->
    <title>View Users</title>
</head>
<style>
    .login-panel {
        margin-top: 150px;
    }
    .table {
        margin-top: 50px;

    }

</style>

<body>

<div class="table-scrol">
    <h1 align="center">All the Users</h1>

<div class="table-responsive"><!--this is used for responsive display in mobile and other devices-->


    <table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped" style="table-layout: fixed">
        <thead>

        <tr>

            <th>User Id</th>
            <th>User Name</th>
            <th>User E-mail</th>
            <th>User Pass</th>
            <th>Delete User</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>

        <?php
        include("database/db_conection.php");
        $view_users_query="select * from users";//select query for viewing users.
        $run=mysqli_query($dbcon,$view_users_query);//here run the sql query.

        while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($run))//while look to fetch the result and store in a array $row.
        {
            $user_id=$row[0];
            $user_name=$row[1];
            $user_pass=$row[2];
            $user_email=$row[3];
            



        ?>

        <tr>
<!--here showing results in the table -->
            <td><?php echo $user_id;  ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $user_name;  ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $user_email;  ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $user_pass;  ?></td>
            <td><a href="delete.php?del=<?php echo $user_id ?>"><button class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button></a></td> <!--btn btn-danger is a bootstrap button to show danger-->
        </tr>

        <?php } ?>

    </table>
        </div>
</div>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Что значит в таблицу вывести?

Comment: Надо вывести к примеру, только тех пользователей у которых буква V главная.

Answer (score 0):

Это сделать довольно просто, вам нужно всего лишь указать критерий по которым вы хотите сделать выборку и БД, за это отвечает оператор **WHERE**.
Допустим у вас таблица **'user'**

> id| user  |ukraine
>    1 |qwery  |   0
>    2 |qwerty2|  1`

запросто должен быть

```
SELECT * FROM user WHERE ukraine = 1;
```

Comment: а как потом в php написать, чтоб выводил на сайт только их?

Comment: @Brandabul ответ уже будет содержать только пользователей которые относятся к Украине и ничего лишнего, останется просто сделать отображение, а как это сделать решайте сами)

Comment: @Brandabul вот тут $view_users_query="select * from users";